# adjust corners and crop the image openCV

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing, opencv

I am using open CV,in IOS.  I already detected the boundary of the paper sheet in an Image as show in image and , Now I have to drag these boundary line on touch for adjusting the crop frame. how we can adjust boundary line and how we can crop image inside the boundary?

This is possible in openCV or I use openGL for this?

@moosgummi : I call your method in below method

```
- (cv::Mat)finshWork:(cv::Mat &)image
{

Mat img0 =image;

Mat img1;
cvtColor(img0, img1, CV_RGB2GRAY);

// apply your filter
Canny(img1, img1, 100, 200);

// find the contours
vector< vector<cv::Point> > contours;
findContours(img1, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


// you could also reuse img1 here
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1);

// CV_FILLED fills the connected components found
drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);


// let's create a new image now
Mat crop(img0.rows, img0.cols, CV_8UC3);

// set background to green
crop.setTo(Scalar(0,255,0));

// and copy the magic apple
img0.copyTo(crop, mask);

// normalize so imwrite(...)/imshow(...) shows the mask correctly!
normalize(mask.clone(), mask, 0.0, 255.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);



std::vector<cv::Point> biggestContour = contours[contours.size()-1];

NSLog(@"%d",biggestContour[0].x);
NSLog(@"%d",biggestContour[0].y);

cv::Mat paperImage =[self getPaperAreaFromImage:image:biggestContour];


//return crop;
return paperImage;

}
```

Thanks All

[image]

Comment: How did you create the grid? Would you be willing to share some sample code? I have similar questions, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269432/perspective-transform-crop-in-ios-with-opencv

Comment: @Gryphon I am interested to know this as well. How did you create the grid?

Comment: @Gryphon please see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594391/ios-drawing-a-rectangle-on-an-imageview-and-adjusting-borders

Comment: @alandalusi this is example image of genius scan, I am detecting corners through openCV.

Comment: @Gryphon Aha.. Understood. So now we have the same quest. BTW, Did the code above work fine with you to detect the boundaries?

Comment: @alandalusi I change that code in real implementation, at start I am using above code, but it's pick the boundary of any single object in image, and mask the outer portion with other color, So In my opinion it's not useful now for image paper corner detection, I use another code for detect paper boundary and corner.

Comment: @Gryphon is your other code faster? I tried other codes but all are very slow. check a wondeful app called SayText, their detection algorithm is real-time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you got the corners you have to deskewing the paper and "extract" it to a new image.

You should do the following:

1. Sort corner points (the order matters; they must be in the same order in both vectors)
2. [`cv::getAffineTransform`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#Mat%20getAffineTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst%29)
3. [`cv::warpAffine`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpAffine%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29)

I wrote myself a helper function, which takes a `std::vector` with four `cv::Point` in it and sorts them in clockwise order beginning in the upper left. For more information on this topic take a look at these thread:

- [Sort points in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order)
- [Sort Four Points in Clockwise Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242404/sort-four-points-in-clockwise-order/242509#242509)
- [Sorting of Points in 2D space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861595/sorting-of-points-in-2d-space)

Another thing you should take into account is the size of the paper you want to extract. In my example I assume you're extracting a DIN A4 paper (210x297mm). Feel free to edit `paperWidth` and `paperHeight` inside my code.

**Combining everything looks like this:**

```
// Helper
cv::Point getCenter( std::vector<cv::Point> points ) {

    cv::Point center = cv::Point( 0.0, 0.0 );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++ ) {
        center.x += points[ i ].x;
        center.y += points[ i ].y;
    }

    center.x = center.x / points.size();
    center.y = center.y / points.size();

    return center;

}

// Helper;
// 0----1
// |    |
// |    |
// 3----2
std::vector<cv::Point> sortSquarePointsClockwise( std::vector<cv::Point> square ) {

    cv::Point center = getCenter( square );

    std::vector<cv::Point> sorted_square;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < square.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( (square[i].x - center.x) < 0 && (square[i].y - center.y) < 0 ) {
            switch( i ) {
                case 0:
                    sorted_square = square;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[1] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[2] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[3] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[0] );
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[2] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[3] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[0] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[1] );
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[3] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[0] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[1] );
                    sorted_square.push_back( square[2] );
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return sorted_square;

}

// Helper
float distanceBetweenPoints( cv::Point p1, cv::Point p2 ) {

    if( p1.x == p2.x ) {
        return abs( p2.y - p1.y );
    }
    else if( p1.y == p2.y ) {
        return abs( p2.x - p1.x );
    }
    else {
        float dx = p2.x - p1.x;
        float dy = p2.y - p1.y;
        return sqrt( (dx*dx)+(dy*dy) );
    }
}

cv::Mat getPaperAreaFromImage( cv::Mat image, std::vector<cv::Point> square )
{

    // declare used vars
    int paperWidth  = 210; // in mm, because scale factor is taken into account
    int paperHeight = 297; // in mm, because scale factor is taken into account
    cv::Point2f imageVertices[4];
    float distanceP1P2;
    float distanceP1P3;
    BOOL isLandscape = true;
    int scaleFactor;
    cv::Mat paperImage;
    cv::Mat paperImageCorrected;
    cv::Point2f paperVertices[4];

    // sort square corners for further operations
    square = sortSquarePointsClockwise( square );

    // rearrange to get proper order for getPerspectiveTransform()
    imageVertices[0] = square[0];
    imageVertices[1] = square[1];
    imageVertices[2] = square[3];
    imageVertices[3] = square[2];

    // get distance between corner points for further operations
    distanceP1P2 = distanceBetweenPoints( imageVertices[0], imageVertices[1] );
    distanceP1P3 = distanceBetweenPoints( imageVertices[0], imageVertices[2] );

    // calc paper, paperVertices; take orientation into account
    if ( distanceP1P2 > distanceP1P3 ) {
        scaleFactor =  ceil( lroundf(distanceP1P2/paperHeight) ); // we always want to scale the image down to maintain the best quality possible
        paperImage = cv::Mat( paperWidth*scaleFactor, paperHeight*scaleFactor, CV_8UC3 );
        paperVertices[0] = cv::Point( 0, 0 );
        paperVertices[1] = cv::Point( paperHeight*scaleFactor, 0 );
        paperVertices[2] = cv::Point( 0, paperWidth*scaleFactor );
        paperVertices[3] = cv::Point( paperHeight*scaleFactor, paperWidth*scaleFactor );
    }
    else {
        isLandscape = false;
        scaleFactor =  ceil( lroundf(distanceP1P3/paperHeight) ); // we always want to scale the image down to maintain the best quality possible
        paperImage = cv::Mat( paperHeight*scaleFactor, paperWidth*scaleFactor, CV_8UC3 );
        paperVertices[0] = cv::Point( 0, 0 );
        paperVertices[1] = cv::Point( paperWidth*scaleFactor, 0 );
        paperVertices[2] = cv::Point( 0, paperHeight*scaleFactor );
        paperVertices[3] = cv::Point( paperWidth*scaleFactor, paperHeight*scaleFactor );
    }

    cv::Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform( imageVertices, paperVertices );
    cv::warpPerspective(_image, paperImage, warpMatrix, paperImage.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT );

    // we want portrait output
    if ( isLandscape ) {
        cv::transpose(paperImage, paperImageCorrected);
        cv::flip(paperImageCorrected, paperImageCorrected, 1);
        return paperImageCorrected;
    }

    return paperImage;

}
```

**Usage:**

```
// ... get paper square ...

cv::Mat paperImage = getPaperAreaFromImage( srcImage, paperSquare );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it executed without any error , but image not shown in output, sometime imageView black and sometime Gray, any Idea?

Comment: Did you sort your contours to really get the biggest one? This code is working. I'm using it in an app right now, which has no problems ...

Comment: yes, I pass the biggest square to your method, and its work fine.. Thanks a lot.  but now issue is when My image width is greater then image height it rotate the cropped image, and also inverse the character in images some time, Really I am struggling very much, you help me a lot thanks

Comment: Just skip the `if ( isLandscape ) { ... }` part inside the `getPaperAreaFromImage` function – that's it :)

Comment: The code by @moosgummi works, but what about adjusting the crop frame?

Comment: @moosgummi you have any idea about adjusting the crop frame?

Comment: I'll do a bit of research. How are you displaying the frame? Are you using OpenCV to draw it inside the image? Or anything else?

Comment: yes, I use openCV to draw boundary around paper, now I have to adjust these boundary lines by touches, but I think it is not possible in openCV, it is difficult for me to convert corner points into uitouch points mean (320,480). do you have any solution or idea regarding adjusting border lines by touches, as Genius scan app do? you can also add me on Skype gauravk.cql   thanks

Comment: I found a class called BJImageCropper which allows you to nicly adjust the borders using your fingers but only to a Rectangular shape. Any idea how we can extend it to support shapes like genuis scan?

Comment: @alandalusi  I already use this before, but it always crop rectangle area :(, So i leave it.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is :

1. Feed the 4 corners that you have found and the 4 real corners of the image to [`cv::getPerspectiveTransform`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-getperspectivetransform). It will give you a matrix of the perspective transformation that will warp the quadrangle to the whole image.
2. Use [`cv::WarpPerspective`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_geometric_image_transformations.html#warpPerspective) to create the image you want.

The links will take you to the documentation.

EDIT : You could use `cv::findHomography` to do step 1. But this is more about having a lot of corresponding points and outliers.

EDIT : Here is an example. It is with the C interface but you could easily make it to work with the c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    // cvLoadImage determines an image type and creates datastructure with appropriate size
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    IplImage* img1 = cvCreateImage(
            cvSize(img->width, img->height),
            img->depth,
            img->nChannels
            );

    cvNamedWindow( "out", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "out", img1 );
    // create a window. Window name is determined by a supplied argument
    cvNamedWindow( argv[1], CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    // Display an image inside and window. Window name is determined by a supplied argument
    cvShowImage( argv[1], img );

    // The part you need
    // Here is the points that you take the image from (the small quadrangle)
    CvPoint2D32f first[4] = {
      {0,0},
      {(img->width /4)* 3, img->height /4    },
      { img->width /4    ,(img->height /4) *3},
      {(img->width /4)* 3,(img->height /4) *3},
    };
    // Here are the points that you draw the quadrangle into (the four corners)
    CvPoint2D32f second[4] = {
      {0,0},
      {img->width,0},
      {0,img->height},
      {img->width,img->height}
    };
    // The part you need
    CvMat *transform = cvCreateMat(3,3, CV_32F);
    cvGetPerspectiveTransform(first,second, transform);
    cvWarpPerspective(img, img1, transform, CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS,
        cvScalarAll(0));
    // End of part you need

    cvShowImage( "out", img1 );


    // wait indefinitely for keystroke
    cvWaitKey(0);
    // release pointer to an object
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    // Destroy a window
    cvDestroyWindow( argv[1] );
}
```

You should replace the array `first` with end points of the quadrangle you have found.

EDIT : Here are some samples. I haven't looked them very well.

[Geometric Image Transformations](http://www.adaptive-vision.com/en/technical_data/documentation/filters/GeometricImageTransformations/index.html)

[cvGetPerspectiveTransform](http://www.adaptive-vision.com/en/technical_data/documentation/filters/GeometricImageTransformations/cvGetPerspectiveTransform.html)

Comment: can you provide any link or example regarding this.