# iOS: Drawing a Rectangle on an ImageView and Adjusting Borders

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

Attached [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqlmy.jpg) is a screenshot from an app called GeniusScan where you can photograph any document and an adjustable rectangular grid shows on the imageview. You can easily adjust the borders of the grid with your fingers to select the portion of the image that you want to scan. It will be then transformed into the correct prospective.

1- How can I draw and interact with the grid on the imageview?

2- How can I return the corner points of the grid to my view controller.

[image]

Update: I found a wonderful class called BJImageCropper which allows to use fingers to ajust the borders, but only for a box like rectangle. Can anyone suggest how it can be updated to support shapes like in the GeniusScan app?

Comment: This doesn't seem a OpenCV related question. A better tag would *obj-c*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dude:

I created a demo that solves both questions:

1- How can I draw and interact with the grid on the imageview?

By Adding 4 views that will act as interactive control points by adding UIPanGestureRecognizer and then drawing the grid using CAShapeLayer on top of your view.

2- How can I return the corner points of the grid to my view controller.

You must keep references to the four control points of your grid.

Here's the link to my [code](https://github.com/darioalessandro/Salami.git).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually drawing on top of UIImageView. It's actually an overlay (view) on top of the UIImageView. You need to keep track of 4 points (have 4 views as subview of the layer), track their positions, once moved, use `drawRect:` to draw lines based on the 4 points.

The way I've implemented it in my app is, I overlay the UIImageView with a transparent 'SelectionView' (a custom view that I wrote). The selectionView contains 4 custom subview of class 'Vertex'. The vertex talk back to the selectionView via protocol method every time user touches/moves it (it's actually not important which vertex moved, just that it moved):

```
- (void)vertexMoved:(Vertex *)vertex;
```

Then the selectionView knows that it needs to re-draw, so it calls `setNeedsDisplay` which calls internally calls `drawRect` (you should never call `drawRect`) where I do the actual drawing of the bounding rect. Basically, iterate through each vertex and draw a line using Quartz APIs and fill it with semi transparent/hollow color.

This is how I am doing it atleast, I am sure there are other ways.

Comment: @0xSina thanks for answer..how we adjust SelectionView on the top of image view, so it cover only the biggest rectangle area in image. mean how we can track the points and make selection view that size... thanks