# Boundry detect paper sheet opencv

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opencv

I am new in openCV, I already detect edge of paper sheet but my result image is blurred after draw lines on edge, How I can draw lines on edges of paper sheet so my image quality remain unaffected.

what I am Missing..

My code is below.

Many thanks.

[image]

```
-(void)forOpenCV
{
   if( imageView.image != nil )
   {

      cv::Mat greyMat=[self cvMatFromUIImage:imageView.image];
      vector<vector<cv::Point> > squares;

      cv::Mat img= [self debugSquares: squares: greyMat ];


      imageView.image =[self UIImageFromCVMat: img];

   }

}


- (cv::Mat) debugSquares: (std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >) squares : (cv::Mat &)image
{
NSLog(@"%lu",squares.size());

// blur will enhance edge detection

Mat blurred(image);
medianBlur(image, blurred, 9);

Mat gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;

// find squares in every color plane of the image
for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
{
    int ch[] = {c, 0};
    mixChannels(&image, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

    // try several threshold levels
    const int threshold_level = 2;
    for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++)
    {
        // Use Canny instead of zero threshold level!
        // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
        if (l == 0)
        {
            Canny(gray0, gray, 10, 20, 3); //

            // Dilate helps to remove potential holes between edge segments
            dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));
        }
        else
        {
            gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level;
        }

        // Find contours and store them in a list
        findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        // Test contours
        vector<cv::Point> approx;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
            // to the contour perimeter
            approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

            // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
            // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
            // contour orientation
            if (approx.size() == 4 &&
                fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
            {
                double maxCosine = 0;

                for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                    maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                }

                if (maxCosine < 0.3)
                    squares.push_back(approx);
            }
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"%lu",squares.size());


for( size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++ )
{


    cv:: Rect rectangle = boundingRect(Mat(squares[i]));
    if(i==squares.size()-1)////Detecting Rectangle here
    {
        const cv::Point* p = &squares[i][0];


        int n = (int)squares[i].size();

         NSLog(@"%d",n);



        line(image, cv::Point(507,418), cv::Point(507+1776,418+1372), Scalar(255,0,0),2,8);

        polylines(image, &p, &n, 1, true, Scalar(255,255,0), 5, CV_AA);



        fx1=rectangle.x;
        fy1=rectangle.y;
        fx2=rectangle.x+rectangle.width;
        fy2=rectangle.y+rectangle.height;


        line(image, cv::Point(fx1,fy1), cv::Point(fx2,fy2), Scalar(0,0,255),2,8);


    }



}


return image;
}
```

Comment: Hi @QueueOverFlow, I am referring your opencv code to do the thing similar to what you've did. I've a doubt in it. What does the function angle(arg1, arg2, arg3) refer to in your above code? Can you please help me?

Comment: can you add the angle function?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Mat blurred(image);
```

you need to do

```
Mat blurred = image.clone();
```

Because the first line does not copy the image, but just creates a second pointer to the same data.
When you blurr the image, you are also changing the original.
What you need to do instead is, to create a real copy of the actual data and operate on this copy.

The [OpenCV reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) states:

> by using a copy constructor or assignment operator, where on the right side it can
>   be a matrix or expression, see below. Again, as noted in the introduction, matrix assignment is O(1) operation because it only copies the header and increases the reference counter.
>
> Mat::clone() method can be used to get a full (a.k.a. deep) copy of the matrix when you need it.

Comment: +1 for you, image quality is good now, but now not detect the edge of paper, now draw rectangle on complete view

Comment: you have to make sure that you are using the blurred image for contour extraction. For example `mixChannels(&image, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);` should probably be `mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);`. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i already modify most of my code ,my this problem is 90 % solved.  I wants to know how We can crop that boundary area? please look on my another question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098073/adjust-corners-and-crop-the-image-opencv

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is **easily solved by doing the entire processing on a copy** of the original image. That way, after you get all the points of the square you can **draw the lines on the original image** and it will not be blurred.

The second problem, which is cropping, can be solved by defining a ROI (region of interested) in the original image and then copying it to a new Mat. I've demonstrated that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317919/176769):

```
// Setup a Region Of Interest
cv::Rect roi;
roi.x = 50
roi.y = 10
roi.width = 400;
roi.height = 450;

// Crop the original image to the area defined by ROI
cv::Mat crop = original_image(roi);

cv::imwrite("cropped.png", crop);
```